# Why does gradle sync happen after creating new Activity?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Why does gradle sync happen after creating new Activity?

Any way to stop this unnecessary build (which takes a huge time in big projects) without any impact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not unnecessary. When you create a new activity using the automatic option for it, AS will also add an entry for it in you manifest file. This is most likely why it syncs with Gradle as that will also reload the manifest file (among other things).

It should also be mentioned that a Gradle sync is not a full project build. It can take some time in larger projects sure, but if it's taking an extremely long time (I'dd say more then 5-10s) you might want to have a look at your Gradle setup and see if there are any sore spots in it. If you are using the Kotlin DSL then building your build scripts will naturally take more time and this is one of the draw backs of using them.

Also how often do you create new activities? For me this is not something I do much at all (on average maybe once a week at best). I don't think it would save any time and probably cost more even if you could disable it (which I doubt you can as, like I stated above, it is needed). If it really costs you that much time you have to optimize your Gradle setup, otherwise their will be other spots in your workflow where you can save more time with less effort.